# Find higher tops and lower bottoms in dataframe of stock close prices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, stock

I have a dataframe

```
company_name = "BERGEPAINT.BO"
start_date = "2021-01-01"
end_date = "2021-04-30"
df = yf.download(company_name, start=start_date, end=end_date)
df1 = df.drop(columns=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Adj Close', 'Volume'])
```

Thus my df1 became,

[image]

I want to find values of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, a, b and c as shown in figure from df1 (Close)

[image]

Is there any easiest way in pandas, scipy or sklearn which can give these higher tops and lower tops of dataframe?

I have updated the code as

```
n = 5
df1['min'] = df1.iloc[argrelextrema(df1['Close'].values, np.less_equal,order=n)[0]]['Close']
df1['max'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df1['Close'].values, np.greater_equal,order=n)[0]]['Close']
```

which gives me,

[image]

But, finding wave patterns 1,2,3,4,5,a,b and c is what the question is. Can anyone help to resolve the problem,?

Comment: What exactly constitutes a wave sequence? Like is it required for 5 > 3 > 1 and a > 4 > 2? And will the sequence occur many times throughout the series or does it only occur once with 5 as the global max?

Comment: yes and sequence can also occur many times in a series

Comment: *"higher tops and lower bottoms [of a stock timeseries]"* doesn't tell us whether they were intraday highs, opens, closes. Or do you simply mean *"classify these daily close prices into rising/falling"*? Also, you don't say what 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, a, b and c refer to: they're all daily close prices? Not opens, or intraday prices.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example of your dataframe so we can run this code ([mcve]); best to replace `yf.download()` with just `df1 = pd.DataFrame(...)`